# Sending messages to ActiveMQ Artemis with Spring's JmsTemplate is very slow

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis

I can only publish about 1600 small string msgs/sec to Apache Artemis. I have tried on two machines and gotten same performance.  I expected something much faster. Is that expected sending speed for a single thread? Should I parallelize the sending with a few threads?

The broker and the publishing app are on the same host.  No listener is subscribed to the topic. I'm using:

- JMS API
- Apache Artemis 2.20.0
- Java 18 64 bit
- Oracle Linux 8
- Spring Boot 2.6.5

Spring Boot `application.properties` includes:

```xml
spring.jms.pub-sub-domain=true
```

`broker.xml` has:

```xml
<persistence-enabled>false</persistence-enabled>
```

Spring's JmsTemplate is setup like this (THIS WAS WRONG):

```java
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.JmsPoolConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
 ...
JmsPoolConnectionFactory poolingFactory = new JmsPoolConnectionFactory();
poolingFactory.setConnectionFactory(new ActiveMQConnectionFactory());
jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(poolingFactory);
```

To publish messages I just call this in a loop:

```java
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(jmsQueue, message);
```

Setting up the JmsTemplate in Spring like this works:

```java
@Autowired
JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

@PostConstruct
void setup() {
        JmsPoolConnectionFactory poolingFactory = new JmsPoolConnectionFactory();
        poolingFactory.setConnectionFactory(new ActiveMQConnectionFactory());
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(poolingFactory);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're running into a [long-standing anti-pattern](https://activemq.apache.org/jmstemplate-gotchas) with Spring's `JmsTemplate`. In short, it creates and closes a JMS connection, session, and producer *every* time it sends a messages. It was not designed to be used with a bare `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` implementation. It was meant to be used with an implementation that provides some kind of pooling.

As a proof-of-concept I spun up a fresh instance of ActiveMQ Artemis 2.20.0 and set `<persistence-enabled>false</persistence-enabled>` in `broker.xml`. Then I ran this command:

```
$ ./artemis producer --destination topic://foo --threads 50 --message-count 100000
```

This command will start 50 threads which will each use the core JMS client to send 100,000 messages to the JMS topic `foo` for a total of 5,000,000 messages. On my laptop that command finished in around 40.6 seconds for an average rate of 122,980.1 msgs/sec which is significantly faster than the 1,600 you're seeing.

ActiveMQ Artemis has a non-blocking architecture designed to maximize throughput at scale so running just a couple of threads isn't a good way to test performance. I recommend revising your "test" to use a pooling connection factory with significantly more threads or perhaps use the command-line tools that ship with the broker. [This pool](https://github.com/messaginghub/pooled-jms) was forked from the ActiveMQ project and it is battle tested. You could also potentially use Spring's [`CachingConnectionFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/connection/CachingConnectionFactory.html) for a simple solution.

You may also be interested in the new [performance tools](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/perf-tools.html) just released with [ActiveMQ Artemis 2.21.0](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/).

Comment: Thanks! Do you recommend using this:   https://github.com/messaginghub/pooled-jms

Comment: Yes. I updated my answer with a few more details to make this clear. Hope that helps!

Comment: I've tried it using the syntax I added above.  Still slow.  Am I using that correctly?  I could forget Spring & JMS and use the Artemis Core API but would like to get this fixed, somehow.

Comment: What exactly do you mean that you, "tried it using the syntax I added above"? Are you saying you used the `artemis producer` command? Please clarify.

Comment: I tried sending messages using the JmsTemplate configured like in the edited code above with JmsPoolConnectionFactory and it's still slow.

Comment: Are you seeing the same 1600 msgs/sec? If not, what exactly are you seeing? How many threads are you spinning up to send messages? What performance do you see when using `artemis producer` with a bunch of threads? Is your application on GitHub or something where I can reproduce the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: I can get up to 20k msgs/sec now using JMS after fixing an issue.  Still hoped for faster.  Test is here is you get a chance to look:  
 http://www.topazdevelopment.com/test0.tgz